# Searching for item in JSON returned from API query with Node

Tags: json, node.js

I'm at the very beginning of my Node journey and writing my first tiny app. I want to query a stock code from markitondemand.com and return the current stock price. I've got the query and response working fine, but I can't work out how to sort through the returned data to extract just the current price. Here is the code I am running:

```
var http = require('http');
var options = {
  host: 'dev.markitondemand.com',
  port: 80,
  path: '/MODApis/Api/v2/Quote/jsonp?symbol=AAPL&callback=myFunction',
  method: 'GET'
};

http.request(options, function(res) {
  console.log('STATUS: ' + res.statusCode);
  res.setEncoding('utf8');
  res.on('data', function (chunk) {
    console.log(chunk);    
  });
}).end();
```

This is the data I receive back from the server:

```
myFunction({"Status":"SUCCESS","Name":"Apple Inc","Symbol":"AAPL","LastPrice":100.33,"Change":-0.0799999999999983,"ChangePercent":-0.0796733393088321,"Timestamp":"Fri May 27 15:59:00 UTC-04:00 2016","MSDate":42517.6659722222,"MarketCap":549550050250,"Volume":3169443,"ChangeYTD":105.26,"ChangePercentYTD":-4.68364050921528,"High":100.47,"Low":99.26,"Open":99.49})
```

How do I search through this to extract the 100.33 from the "LastPrice":100.33 key value pair? I thought of using the .filters method, but I don't believe what is being returned is a properly formatted array?

Thank you!

Comment: It's unsafe to use chunks directly without making sure the response ended. [The doc](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/anatomy-of-an-http-transaction/) explains and gives alternatives.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Request JSON instead of jsonp. That way you can use JSON.parse. jsonp is designed for browsers trying to work around CORS policies. Since you are running a server, you don't need to worry about such things.

URL (notice **/json?** instead of **/jsonp?**):

```
http://dev.markitondemand.com/MODApis/Api/v2/Quote/json?symbol=AAPL
```

CODE:

```
const json = JSON.parse(chunk);
console.log(json.LastPrice);
```

SIDE NOTE:

If that API sends chunked JSON, you may need to accumulate the chunks before parsing. Something like:

```
  let data = '';

  res.on('data', function (chunk) {
    data += chunk;  
  });

  res.on('end', function () {
    const json = JSON.parse(data);
    console.log(json.LastPrice);
  });
```

Comment: And the reason this works is because in javascript `a = {"abc": 1, "def" : 2}` is an object where you can do `a.abc` or `a["abc"]`.

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you so much! I'll also have a look at how I handle chunks as suggested by yourself and coyotte508. Thanks again!